# I have been using cxf 3.0.16 version jar for rest service use, but after migrating to 3.2.4. Its getting error while service bean creation

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I have been using cxf 3.0.16 version jar for rest service use, but after migrating to 3.2.4. It's getting error while service bean creation.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid media type string: /application/json
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
```

Comment: Share code here that would be helpful to find out the actual root cause

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It got resolved,it can be said that it was very silly reason. In latest version of cxf, It's enforcing the developer to give correct MIME type in @Produce arguments of service method/class. If it finds it unnatural or any incorrect kind of. it raises this error.